# Getting Specific Value From Nested Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
get_fru = 
  {"default_fru_device"=>
    {:name=>"default_fru_device",
    "chassis_type"=>"Other",
    "board_manufacturer"=>"IBM",
    "product_name"=>"System x3650 M4"
    }
   }
```

I know that if I wanted to get the value of `product_name`, I could simply do `get_fru["default_fru_device"]["product_name"]` which would, in this example, return `System x3650 M4`.

However, If I wanted to get the values `IBM` and `System x3650 M4` and make them display as a single string that said `IBM System x3650 M4`, how would I go about achieving that?

Comment: You want to concatenate strings in ruby? If so, you can use `"#{get_fru["default_fru_device"]["board_manufacturer"]} #{get_fru["default_fru_device"]["product_name"]}"`

Comment: Thanks - but is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: "System" is missing from the string. Is it planned?

Comment: You can use `+` (concatenates when used with String): `my_string = get_fru["default_fru_device"]["board_manufacturer"]} + " " + get_fru["default_fru_device"]["product_name"]`. But @EricDuminil's answer is great.

Comment: @EricDuminil Sorry, I forgot to include "System".  Was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Hash#values_at`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) and [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join) :

```
get_fru["default_fru_device"].values_at('board_manufacturer', 'product_name').join(' ')
#=> "IBM System x3650 M4"
```

Comment: Thanks - nice and clean.  Was what I was looking for.